# Entity framework model is not geting updated properly when adding new columns in SP

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a .net application in which Im using Entity framework and model concept for connecting to DB. Now I have modified my Stored Procedure in the DB to retrieve two more fields from the table. When I update (*Update Model from Database option* in Model Browser), in my model the updated fields is included as last columns. (In the Stored Procedure, I added these columns in the middle). I have tried by delete this SP from model (from **Function Imports** $ **Stored Procedures/ Functions** section) and add as new one to the model and also tried updating the model etc but nothing worked.

I have written the SP like below

```
Select StudentID, 
       SC.SeatNo, 
       CourseId,  
       DOB AS Date of birth, 
       SC.Country,
       SC.City, 
       CASE WHEN SC.IsHostler = 0 THEN 'False' 
            ELSE 'True' 
       END AS Hostler, 
       Location,
       Region
FROM StudentDetails AS SC
  INNER JOIN Course AS C ON SC.CourseId = C.CourseId 
  left join Seats as S ON SC.SeatNo=S.SeatNo 
GROUP BY SC.SeatNo,
         CourseId,
         DOB, 
         SC.Country,
         SC.City,
         SC.IsHostler,
         Location,
         Region
```

The SP is somewhat like the above. In this  DOB $  SC.IsHostler is added as new fields while updating SP.

**In model its retrieving like** 
StudentID,
SeatNo,
CourseId,
Country,
City,
Location,
Region,
DOB,
Hostler

**I need it to be like** 
StudentID,
SeatNo,
CourseId,
DOB,
Country,
City,
Hostler,
Location,
Region

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the designer surface of the EDMX designer and click Update Model From Database.

[image]

All entities are refreshed by default, new entities are only added if you select them.

Comment: Yes. This way I have updated my model. The problem is that the newly added fields will be added at the end of the column list. Im not getting it in an order in which I have given in the SP. As Im writing the retrieved data into an excel, the order of fields should be same as in the SP.

Comment: could you rearrange in database and then update it ?

Comment: eg: by old SP it was returning like Id,Name,Address in the same order I was able to retrieve fom model. After modifying SP its returning like Id,Name,Age,Subject,Address but from model after updating it, its getting in an order Id,Name,Address,Age,Subject. This is the problem.

Comment: its getting sorted ,right?.so add sort in SP..could you show ur SP

Comment: Select StudentID, 
 SC.SeatNo, 
 CourseId,  
 DOB AS Date of birth, 
 SC.Country,
 SC.City, 
 CASE WHEN SC.IsHostler = 0 
 THEN 'False' 
 ELSE 'True' 
 END AS Hostler, 
 Location,
 Region

 FROM StudentDetails AS SC INNER JOIN 
 Course AS C ON SC.CourseId =C.CourseId 
 left join Seats as S ON SC.SeatNo=S.SeatNo 


GROUP BY SC.SeatNo, 
 CourseId,  
 DOB, 
 SC.Country,
 SC.City, SC.IsHostler,Location, Region

The SP is somewhat like the above. In this  DOB $  SC.IsHostler is added as new fields while updating SP.

Comment: Select StudentID, 
SC.SeatNo, 
CourseId,  
DOB AS Date of birth, 
SC.Country,
SC.City, 
CASE WHEN SC.IsHostler = 0 
THEN 'False' 
ELSE 'True' 
END AS Hostler, 
Location,
Region
FROM StudentDetails AS SC INNER JOIN 
Course AS C ON SC.CourseId =C.CourseId 
left join Seats as S ON SC.SeatNo=S.SeatNo 
GROUP BY SC.SeatNo, 
CourseId,  
DOB, 
SC.Country,
SC.City, SC.IsHostler,Location, Region
The SP is somewhat like the above. In this  DOB $  SC.IsHostler is added as new fields while updating SP.
In model its retrieving like 
StudentID,
SeatNo,
CourseId,
Country,
City,
Location,
Region,
DOB,
Hostler

Comment: @Sudha please edit your question and include the SP and other details as well so that others can also understand at a glance and help you

Comment: In the EntityModel.Designer.cs class a partial class is being created for the SP's (entities). In that the properties is coming like last come last edited (added) order, not in the same order as given in SP. Editing in this designer file is not a good practice right? Then how can I change that order?